# Instalação do Firebase no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Estava assistindo a um [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1rlT5KQ0yE) sobre a instalação do Firebase e ele diz para entrar em: File > Project Structure, e abre essa janela da imagem:

[image: video]

Porém, o próximo passo é clicar em Cloud, mas quando entro em Project Struture, a seguinte janela aparece, sem o Cloud:

[image: tela]

Existe um outro local para configurar isso?

Comment: já pesquisei em outros lugares mas sempre o processo de instalação é esse

Comment: esse curso me ajudou bastante, https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352?product=5483321653723136&_ga=1.33938472.843565695.1438022865%3Futm_source%3Dblog&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=sb_widget_enroll

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse vídeo é antigo. No mesmo lugar onde você usa as bibliotecas, cole:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0"// banco
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0' // autenticador 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0' //arquivos

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // esse
```

Já outro gradle, use:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' // esse

        }
    }
```

Aí é só começar a usar...

Answer (score 3):

A guia Cloud (que contém uma caixa de seleção para adicionar o Firebase a um projeto) foi removida no Android Studio 2.2.

O Android Studio 2.2 tem um assistente completo para ajudá-lo a integrar o Firebase. Você pode encontra-lo em Tools > Firebase.

Aqui tem um link para ajudá-la a adicionar o Firebase: [QuickStart com Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html)